# How to determine exact type in union type in typescript in runtime?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

In typescript, union type is defined as **ParsedValue**, which consists of some basic type and interface **Template**.

After some parsing code as shown below, the parsedValue's type is decided based on type. Now I want to do something based on parsedValue's exact type, which is a subtype in the union type.

However, I found **as** keyword doesn't work due to **Template** is an intrface rather that a class implementation.

Any solution to bypass this problem?

```js
type ParsedValue = string | number | boolean | Template | null

interface Visitor {
    visit(template: Template)
}

class BasicVisitor implements Visitor {
    visit(template: Template) {
    }
}

interface Template {
    accept(visitor: Visitor)
}

function parse(value: string, type: string): ParsedValue {
    if (type == 'template') {
        // return a template instance
    } else if (type === 'string') {
        // return some string
    } else {
        // return null
    }
}

class Field {
    type: string
    value: string
    parsedValue: ParsedValue

    constructor(json any) {
        this.value = json.value.toString()
        this.type = json.type.toString()
        this.parsedValue = parse(this.value, this.type)
    }
}

const field = new Field({
    type: 'template',
    value: 'some template string'
})

const visitor = new BasicVisitor()

if (field.parsedValue !== null && field.parsedValue as Template) {
    // how to bypass this type judgement
    field.parsedValue.accept(visitor)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try out User-Defined Type Guards for run-time type checks and type assertions: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards